# Is there a way to run "setup" only once for the entire suite of Python tests?

Tags: python, testing

I know about the "setUp" and "setUpClass" test fixtures in Python but I have not been able to find a way to implement a setup just once for the entire suite of tests ... no matter if one test or one test class or all test classes are run.

Might anyone know a way to do this?

Robert

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The above answer is only for a TestClass not a TestSuite.